# onChange() count nodes in Ant TreeSelect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I am working on Ant TreeSelect and trying to get number of file selected in the tree.

```
const treeData = [
  {
    title: 'Node1',
    value: '0-0',
    key: '0-0',
    children: [
      {
        title: 'Child Node1',
        value: '0-0-0',
        key: '0-0-0',
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    title: 'Node2',
    value: '0-1',
    key: '0-1',
  },
];

class Demo extends React.Component {
  state = {
    value: ['0-0-0'],
    count: 0
  };

  onChange = value => {
    console.log('onChange ', value);
    console.log('count', value.length);
    this.setState({ value });
    /* click node2 */
    /* Api call to get children value */
    /* build children for node 2 */

  };

  render() {
    const tProps = {
      treeData,
      value: this.state.value,
      onChange: this.onChange,
      treeCheckable: true,
      placeholder: 'Please select',
      style: {
        width: '100%',
      },
    };
    return <TreeSelect {...tProps} />;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Demo />, mountNode);
```

So i got it working using *count* as the example that i provided above. However, if i want to build children of Node2 using an API call. So basically, when i click on Node2, API call will be triggered and loaded to the Tree. *count* wont work anymore. It only count Node2 as 1 item, not counting all of the children. Any suggestion ? Thank you.

My thinking: I think the reason is that, after hitting the API, its loaded to the Tree. But somehow the onChange() is not triggered. Thats why the *count* dont recognize those node. I have no idea.

Comment: Would be helpful if you could provide a jsfiddle link where we can make the changes